# 32bit Server Maximum memory

Tags: windows-server-2003

All,

How much memory a 32bit server running Windows 2003 Server edition can address?

Rgds,

MK

Comment: Try googling it. You'd be amazed. Also, I'm not sure SO is the right forum for questions of this type.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what edition.

Have a look at [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003).  What Windows will actually SEE in 32-bit editions is a bit different.

Also, have a read through [**Physical Address Extensions (PAE)**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283037) which, as others have mentioned, allows 32-bit Windows to address more than 4 GB of memory.

Comment: indeed PAE is the reason 32bit Windows can access all 4 GiB if "only" that much is available. The reason is that there is what is usually referred to as a "memory hole" above 3 GiB, which used to be used for device memory (assigned by the BIOS) but is now quite annoying. You will often see 32bit OSs (not just Windows) without PAE being able to see and access only 3.1 or 3.2 GiB of RAM. PAE fixes that in many cases, though cooperation between BIOS and CPU seems to be necessary. I've seen machines whose CPU had PAE-support, but the BIOS still didn't allow the OS to re-map memory.

Answer (score 1):

4 GiB for **Standard** edition (with PAE). Otherwise:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758523(WS.10).aspx

64 GiB is the absolute maximum for the 32bit versions. I think that limitation is the limitation in PAE.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you calculate it

2^32 = 4294967296 bytes                      .

Comment: Actually wrong ;) ... thanks to PAE they can support way more. Written inside a VM running on a Windows 2003 with 8 GiB :)